# Как узнать развернулись ли изображения на странице ?

Tags: javascript, html

Как узнать развернулись ли изображения на странице ? Через AJAX я создаю картинки в области, потом мне надо вызвать функцию, которая замерит ширину всех фотографий, но только после того, как они приняли свой размер

Comment: В картинок есть событие onloadбего можно отследить.

Comment: Если вы используете jQuery, то jQuery(document).ready()

Comment: @Anovoselof, ready() -- это событие происходит, когда построился DOM.  Не путайте людей.

    $(window).load(function(){
       // код
    });



Comment: спасибо всем